# JavaScript - My variable is "stuck" in a function and I can't get it out

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay this is probably a crazy question, but for some reason I can't for the life of me pass 'body' out of this nested function.

```js
function getFacebookUserInfo(sender_psid) {
  request({
      "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/" + sender_psid,
      "qs": {
        "fields": "first_name,last_name,profile_pic,gender",
        "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
      }
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }
      return (JSON.parse(body));
    });
}
```

Comment: Think about where `return JSON.parse(body)` is returning too. How is it being called?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a return value from a asynchronous function as far as I see. This doesn't work, you either return a promise and do something when the function resolves, or you pass a callback function to the query, which means you do whatever you wanted to do within

```
function ( error, response, body ) {}
```